# Remote server cannot call Axis2 service

Tags: apache-axis

In response to a request we sent, the remote sever makes a WS call to our service. Here is the Tomcat log of one such call.

```
xxx.xx.xxx.x - - [12/May/2016:14:00:46 +0630] "POST /axis2/services/SmsNotificationService​ HTTP/1.1" 500 482
```

The following wsdl is retrieved from `http://xxx.xx.xxx.x:8088/axis2/services/SmsNotificationService?wsdl`

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://www.csapi.org/wsdl/parlayx/sms/notification/v3_1/service" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:interface="http://www.csapi.org/wsdl/parlayx/sms/notification/v3_1/interface" name="parlayx_sms_notification_service" targetNamespace="http://www.csapi.org/wsdl/parlayx/sms/notification/v3_1/service">
  <import namespace="http://www.csapi.org/wsdl/parlayx/sms/notification/v3_1/interface" location="SmsNotificationService?wsdl=parlayx_sms_notification_interface_3_1.wsdl">
</import>
  <binding name="SmsNotificationBinding" type="interface:SmsNotification">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="notifySmsReception">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <input>
        <soap:header message="interface:NotifySOAPHeader" part="NotifySOAPHeader" use="literal">
      </soap:header>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="notifySmsDeliveryReceipt">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <input>
        <soap:header message="interface:NotifySOAPHeader" part="NotifySOAPHeader" use="literal">
      </soap:header>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="SmsNotificationService">
    <port name="SmsNotification" binding="tns:SmsNotificationBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://xxx.xx.xxx.x:8088/axis2/services/SmsNotificationService/"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

I'll post Axis2's generated code and my implementation code for the web service in case it's needed to answer my question.

**SmsNotificationServiceMessageReceiverInOut.java**

```
/**
 * SmsNotificationServiceMessageReceiverInOut.java
 *
 * This file was auto-generated from WSDL
 * by the Apache Axis2 version: 1.7.1  Built on : Feb 20, 2016 (10:01:29 GMT)
 */
package com.nirvasoft.mabsms;


/**
 *  SmsNotificationServiceMessageReceiverInOut message receiver
 */
public class SmsNotificationServiceMessageReceiverInOut extends org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver {
    public void invokeBusinessLogic(
        org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext msgContext,
        org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext newMsgContext)
        throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault {
        try {
            // get the implementation class for the Web Service
            Object obj = getTheImplementationObject(msgContext);

            SmsNotificationServiceSkeleton skel = (SmsNotificationServiceSkeleton) obj;

            //Out Envelop
            org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope envelope = null;

            //Find the axisOperation that has been set by the Dispatch phase.
            org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation op = msgContext.getOperationContext()
                                                                      .getAxisOperation();

            if (op == null) {
                throw new org.apache.axis2.AxisFault(
                    "Operation is not located, if this is doclit style the SOAP-ACTION should specified via the SOAP Action to use the RawXMLProvider");
            }

            java.lang.String methodName;

            if ((op.getName() != null) &&
                    ((methodName = org.apache.axis2.util.JavaUtils.xmlNameToJavaIdentifier(
                            op.getName().getLocalPart())) != null)) {
                if ("notifySmsDeliveryReceipt".equals(methodName)) {
                    org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsDeliveryReceiptResponseE notifySmsDeliveryReceiptResponse3 =
                        null;
                    org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsDeliveryReceiptE wrappedParam =
                        (org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsDeliveryReceiptE) fromOM(msgContext.getEnvelope()
                                                                                                                              .getBody()
                                                                                                                              .getFirstElement(),
                            org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsDeliveryReceiptE.class);

                    notifySmsDeliveryReceiptResponse3 = skel.notifySmsDeliveryReceipt(wrappedParam);

                    envelope = toEnvelope(getSOAPFactory(msgContext),
                            notifySmsDeliveryReceiptResponse3, false,
                            new javax.xml.namespace.QName(
                                "http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/notification/v3_1/local",
                                "notifySmsDeliveryReceiptResponse"));
                } else
                 if ("notifySmsReception".equals(methodName)) {
                    org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsReceptionResponseE notifySmsReceptionResponse6 =
                        null;
                    org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsReceptionE wrappedParam =
                        (org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsReceptionE) fromOM(msgContext.getEnvelope()
                                                                                                                        .getBody()
                                                                                                                        .getFirstElement(),
                            org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsReceptionE.class);

                    notifySmsReceptionResponse6 = skel.notifySmsReception(wrappedParam);

                    envelope = toEnvelope(getSOAPFactory(msgContext),
                            notifySmsReceptionResponse6, false,
                            new javax.xml.namespace.QName(
                                "http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/notification/v3_1/local",
                                "notifySmsReceptionResponse"));
                } else {
                    throw new java.lang.RuntimeException("method not found");
                }

                newMsgContext.setEnvelope(envelope);
            }
        } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
            throw org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(e);
        }
    }

    //
    private org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement toOM(
        org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsDeliveryReceiptE param,
        boolean optimizeContent) throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault {
        try {
            return param.getOMElement(org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsDeliveryReceiptE.MY_QNAME,
                org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory());
        } catch (org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException e) {
            throw org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(e);
        }
    }

    private org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement toOM(
        org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsDeliveryReceiptResponseE param,
        boolean optimizeContent) throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault {
        try {
            return param.getOMElement(org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsDeliveryReceiptResponseE.MY_QNAME,
                org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory());
        } catch (org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException e) {
            throw org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(e);
        }
    }

    private org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement toOM(
        org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.common.v3_1.NotifySOAPHeaderE param,
        boolean optimizeContent) throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault {
        try {
            return param.getOMElement(org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.common.v3_1.NotifySOAPHeaderE.MY_QNAME,
                org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory());
        } catch (org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException e) {
            throw org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(e);
        }
    }

    private org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement toOM(
        org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsReceptionE param,
        boolean optimizeContent) throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault {
        try {
            return param.getOMElement(org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsReceptionE.MY_QNAME,
                org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory());
        } catch (org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException e) {
            throw org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(e);
        }
    }

    private org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement toOM(
        org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsReceptionResponseE param,
        boolean optimizeContent) throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault {
        try {
            return param.getOMElement(org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsReceptionResponseE.MY_QNAME,
                org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory());
        } catch (org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException e) {
            throw org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(e);
        }
    }

    private org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope toEnvelope(
        org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPFactory factory,
        org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsDeliveryReceiptResponseE param,
        boolean optimizeContent, javax.xml.namespace.QName elementQName)
        throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault {
        try {
            org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope emptyEnvelope = factory.getDefaultEnvelope();

            emptyEnvelope.getBody()
                         .addChild(param.getOMElement(
                    org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsDeliveryReceiptResponseE.MY_QNAME,
                    factory));

            return emptyEnvelope;
        } catch (org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException e) {
            throw org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(e);
        }
    }

    private org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsDeliveryReceiptResponseE wrapnotifySmsDeliveryReceipt() {
        org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsDeliveryReceiptResponseE wrappedElement =
            new org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsDeliveryReceiptResponseE();

        return wrappedElement;
    }

    private org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope toEnvelope(
        org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPFactory factory,
        org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsReceptionResponseE param,
        boolean optimizeContent, javax.xml.namespace.QName elementQName)
        throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault {
        try {
            org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope emptyEnvelope = factory.getDefaultEnvelope();

            emptyEnvelope.getBody()
                         .addChild(param.getOMElement(
                    org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsReceptionResponseE.MY_QNAME,
                    factory));

            return emptyEnvelope;
        } catch (org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException e) {
            throw org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(e);
        }
    }

    private org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsReceptionResponseE wrapnotifySmsReception() {
        org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsReceptionResponseE wrappedElement =
            new org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsReceptionResponseE();

        return wrappedElement;
    }

    /**
     *  get the default envelope
     */
    private org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope toEnvelope(
        org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPFactory factory) {
        return factory.getDefaultEnvelope();
    }

    private java.lang.Object fromOM(org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement param,
        java.lang.Class type) throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault {
        try {
            if (org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.common.v3_1.NotifySOAPHeaderE.class.equals(
                        type)) {
                return org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.common.v3_1.NotifySOAPHeaderE.Factory.parse(param.getXMLStreamReaderWithoutCaching());
            }

            if (org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsDeliveryReceiptE.class.equals(
                        type)) {
                return org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsDeliveryReceiptE.Factory.parse(param.getXMLStreamReaderWithoutCaching());
            }

            if (org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsDeliveryReceiptResponseE.class.equals(
                        type)) {
                return org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsDeliveryReceiptResponseE.Factory.parse(param.getXMLStreamReaderWithoutCaching());
            }

            if (org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsReceptionE.class.equals(
                        type)) {
                return org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsReceptionE.Factory.parse(param.getXMLStreamReaderWithoutCaching());
            }

            if (org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsReceptionResponseE.class.equals(
                        type)) {
                return org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsReceptionResponseE.Factory.parse(param.getXMLStreamReaderWithoutCaching());
            }
        } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
            throw org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private org.apache.axis2.AxisFault createAxisFault(java.lang.Exception e) {
        org.apache.axis2.AxisFault f;
        Throwable cause = e.getCause();

        if (cause != null) {
            f = new org.apache.axis2.AxisFault(e.getMessage(), cause);
        } else {
            f = new org.apache.axis2.AxisFault(e.getMessage());
        }

        return f;
    }
} //end of class
```

**SmsNotificationServiceSkeleton.java**

```
/**
 * SmsNotificationServiceSkeleton.java
 *
 * This file was auto-generated from WSDL
 * by the Apache Axis2 version: 1.7.1  Built on : Feb 20, 2016 (10:01:29 GMT)
 */
package com.nirvasoft.mabsms;

import org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsDeliveryReceiptResponseE;

/**
 *  SmsNotificationServiceSkeleton java skeleton for the axisService
 */
public class SmsNotificationServiceSkeleton {
    /**
     * Auto generated method signature
     *
     * @param notifySmsDeliveryReceipt
     * @return notifySmsDeliveryReceiptResponse
     */
    public org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsDeliveryReceiptResponseE notifySmsDeliveryReceipt(
        org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsDeliveryReceiptE notifySmsDeliveryReceipt) {
        System.out.println("correlator = " + notifySmsDeliveryReceipt.getNotifySmsDeliveryReceipt().getCorrelator());
        System.out.println("Status = " + notifySmsDeliveryReceipt.getNotifySmsDeliveryReceipt().getDeliveryStatus().toString());
        return new NotifySmsDeliveryReceiptResponseE();
    }

    /**
     * Auto generated method signature
     *
     * @param notifySmsReception
     * @return notifySmsReceptionResponse
     */
    public org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsReceptionResponseE notifySmsReception(
        org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.sms.notification.v3_1.local.NotifySmsReceptionE notifySmsReception) {
        //TODO : fill this with the necessary business logic
        throw new java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException("Please implement " +
            this.getClass().getName() + "#notifySmsReception");
    }
}
```

The remote server calls `notifySmsDeliveryReceipt`. I think it would help to know the details of the remote call and I would like anyone who knows Axis2 to point out any problem they see in my code.

Comment: Do you have at least a stack trace?  Can you successfully call that SOAP service from SOAP UI or a similar console tool?

Comment: I could call it. The server receives 
    172.16.200.6 - - [12/May/2016:15:47:05 +0630] "POST /axis2/services/SmsNotificationService/services/SmsNotification HTTP/1.1" 500 302
    172.16.200.6 - - [12/May/2016:15:48:10 +0630] "POST /axis2/services/SmsNotificationService HTTP/1.1" 500 302

Comment: Do you see the `500` and `302` error codes?  This looks like a problem to me.  But assuming you had no errors, the next thing to look at would be your Axis2 stubs, which could also have a problem.

Comment: I was using SoapUI. The return was 

`<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>unknown</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`

Comment: Forget about the code for now, because you can't even reach your server properly.  Whence is the WSDL you used to create the project in SOAP UI?  Are you sure it does not have any problems?  Are you sure you are pointing to the correct URL?

Comment: The WSDL was retrieved from `http://localhost:8088/axis2/services/SmsNotificationService?wsdl`. Since I generated the service from a WSDL published by a standards body, I assume it is correct.